# Spring boot JPA many to many association problem

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have many to many relationship between two entities User and forms.
and my classes are below.
User.java

```
public class User {    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    .....
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "userformtable", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "form_id"))
    private List<forms> userform = new ArrayList<forms>();

    // CONSTRUCTOR AND GETTER SETTER    
}
```

AND forms.class

```
public class forms {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String formname;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userform", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> form = new ArrayList<User>();   
}
```

I have database table for relations ship is like below

```
user_id |  form_id
--------------------
1       |       4
--------------------
1       |       6
-------------------
1       |       3
------------------
1       |       7 
=================== 
3       |       3
====================
3       |       7
===================
```

when I try to fetch all user using spring data jpa I do not get user object with id 3. I only get user id.
here is my json response.

```
0: {…}
1: 3 (this record is for user id 3)
2: {…}
```

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my answer and let us know about your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by using @JsonIgnore annotation in forms class.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userform", fetch  = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<User> form = new ArrayList<User>();
```